# How to make database backup in SDcard

Tags: android, android-database

I have made the backup of my database successfully, but the problem is that my backup is saved in the internal memory not in SDcard.

Here is my code:

```
public void exportDatabase()
{
    File sd = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
    File data = Environment.getDataDirectory();
    String currentDBPath = "/data/" + "com.arpanexample.spm" + "/databases/" + Database.DATABASE_NAME;
    String backupDBPath = Database.DATABASE_NAME;
    File currentDB = new File(data, currentDBPath);
    File backupDB = new File(sd, backupDBPath);
    try {
        FileChannel source = new FileInputStream(currentDB).getChannel();
        FileChannel destination = new FileOutputStream(backupDB).getChannel();
        destination.transferFrom(source, 0, source.size());
        source.close();
        destination.close();
        Toast.makeText(context, "Successfully backup your data", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

By default the Context class/SQLiteOpenHelper class do not let you save your database file anywhere else but the internal application storage .ie /data/data/com.you.packagename/databases. You have do get a custom class for handling SQLite databases or roll out your on - Take the SQLiteOpenHelper class in the Android Sources directory and edit it if you know what you are doing. Here is one custom [implementation of SQLiteOpenHelper you can use.](http://snippetrepo.com/snippets/sqliteopenhelper-with-custom-path)

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to try something similar, but did not find proper tutorials.

Later, used FileCache to save content in SD Card.
Caching will help in apps that have connectivity to the internet.

```
package com.sumukh.myApp.anotherjsonparser;

import java.io.File;

import android.content.Context;

public class FileCache {

private File cacheDir;

public FileCache(Context context) {
    // Find the dir to save cached images
    if (android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageState().equals(
            android.os.Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED))
        cacheDir = new File(
                android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),
                "AppCache");
    else
        cacheDir = context.getCacheDir();
    if (!cacheDir.exists())
        cacheDir.mkdirs();
}

public File getFile(String url) {
    String filename = String.valueOf(url.hashCode());
    // String filename = URLEncoder.encode(url);
    File f = new File(cacheDir, filename);
    return f;

}

public void clear() {
    File[] files = cacheDir.listFiles();
    if (files == null)
        return;
    for (File f : files)
        f.delete();
   }

}
```

Hope this helps.